# Ionic always show blank screen after splash screen

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I have an ionic project, so after I run this build

```
ionic cordova run ios -l --consolelogs --target='2E565780-E17E-4358-8DD0-FFA9681D5F8C'
```

usually it is working fine, but somehow now I got error. It is always show me the blank white screen after splash screen is triggered. I already put this function

```
ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.platform);

        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            if (this.platform.is("cordova")) {
                this.statusBar.styleDefault();
                this.splashScreen.hide();
        });
    }
```

on app.component but it seems not triggered. is there work around that I missed? any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Try debug it: and see console for Errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue, it is regarding the plugin that I add, so i tried to do this

1. uninstall plugin
2. remove ios folder
3. fresh install node modules
4. add plugin
5. add ios folder

hope it is help whoever that has same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding a function to execute from your app.component constructor:

```
constructor( ... ){
    this.initializeApp();
}

initializeApp(){
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        if (this.platform.is("cordova")) {
            this.statusBar.show();
            this.statusBar.styleDefault();
            this.splashScreen.hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, I already tried your suggestion, but its not firing the function. any other suggestion?

Comment: Are you certain that platform is cordova? Might it be capacitor?

Comment: yes it is Cordova, I also run and build using cordova not capacitor

Comment: Hm take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66285483/ionic-capacitor-android-splash-screen-responsiveness - it deals with splash screen dimensions and responsiveness, but you might find some details that you can change in different files and it just might be the way to go. It's capacitor, but still...

Comment: Hi thanks for responding! actually I resolved the issue, it is regarding the plugin that I add, so i tried to do this
1. uninstall plugin
2. remove ios folder 
3. fresh install node modules
4. add plugin
5. add ios folder

hope it is help whoever that has same issue.